# Laravel App:before function not being called

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem with an application running Laravel 4.1 and trying to get filters working.

Within my filters file I have the following code residing in my filters.php:

```
echo 'here1';
App::before(function($request)
{
    die('here2');
    //
});
```

When I make a request to the application in my browser, then I get the first echo but I can't get the die to work indicating that this function is not being run.

I am not getting errors on screen or in the logs.

Can anybody shed any light as to why this before function is not being called?

Many thanks, G.

Comment: I've checked in Laravel 4.2 and it's definitely being launched. Are you sure you don't have it defined in file for other environment you use at the moment?

Comment: Make sure your environment is not test as all filter by default are turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Burrow pointed me in the right direction.

Filters are in fact disabled in testing mode as standard in Laravel (thank you Laravel documentation for making this obvious).

So, I put the following code into the configuration file for my testing environment and the filters started working:

```
Route::enableFilters();
```

Many thanks, G.